# How do I call Regex::replace_all when the replacer uses a variable?

Tags: regex, rust

For the following my code, I tried to output the input word followed by a random string. The first function compiles but I don't want it because it does not use the random string. The second function yields a compiler errors.

How do I fix it?

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let cd="rust";
    ok_but_i_dont_want_it(cd);
    compiler_err(cd);
}

fn ok_but_i_dont_want_it(cd:&str){
    let random_str="j93bg8";
    let reg_idnt=Regex::new(r"(?P<ident>[_A-Za-z]{1,}[_A-Za-z0-9]{0,})").unwrap();
    let cd=reg_idnt.replace_all(" rust ","${ident}_{}");
    println!("{}",cd);
}

fn compiler_err(cd:&str){
    let random_str="j93bg8";
    let reg_idnt=Regex::new(r"(?P<ident>[_A-Za-z]{1,}[_A-Za-z0-9]{0,})").unwrap();
    let cd=reg_idnt.replace_all(cd,format!("${ident}_{}",random_str));
    println!("{}",cd);
}
```

```
error: there is no argument named `ident`
  --> src/main.rs:18:47
   |
18 |      let cd=reg_idnt.replace_all(cd,format!("${ident}_{}",random_str));
   |                                               ^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&regex::Captures<'_>,)>` closure, found `String`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecd39833ed67145228db2449a9c4217b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `format!` to handle the `{ident}`, you can [escape](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#escaping) it by doubling up the braces:

```
reg_idnt.replace_all(cd, format!("${{ident}}_{}", random_str));
```

This will cause `format!` to ignore it and the result will be `"{ident}_j93bg8"` which is passed to `replace_all`.

---

You're missing an `.as_str()` to pass the `String` from `format!` as a `&str` to satisfy `Replacer`.

```
format!("${{ident}}_{}", random_str).as_str()
```

See it running on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9eba84a41bcc5c4c16ff2095971ad784)